# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string * string

Tags: php

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string * string

Error in line 10 containing:

```
$value["shoe_quantity"] * $value["shoe_price"], 2);
```

Code:

```
<?php
                if(!empty($_SESSION["ShoeCart"])){
                    $total = 0;
                    foreach ($_SESSION["ShoeCart"] as $key => $value) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $value["shoe_name"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $value["shoe_quantity"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $value["shoe_price"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo number_format($value["shoe_quantity"] * $value["shoe_price"], 2); ?></td>
                            <td><a href="ShoeCart.php?action=delete&ShoeID=<?php echo $value["shoe_id"]; ?>"><span
                                        class="text-danger">Remove Item</span></a></td>

                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $total = $total + ($value["shoe_quantity"] * $value["shoe_price"]);
                    }
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>
                            <th align="right">$ <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></th>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Either "shoe_quantity" or "shoe_price" doesn't contain anything that could be interpreted as a number. Have you googled this error? Have you debugged the code to see what's in those fields when you run the code?

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try it by casting before multiply with eachother,

```
number_format(floatval($value["shoe_quantity"]) * floatval ($value["shoe_price"]), 2)
```

Comment: That's unlikely to work - if the fields contained valid numbers (but stored as strings) then PHP would coerce them to numbers automatically. The error is most likely because in fact one or more of the fields doesn't contain a valid number at all.